Is P/poly included in NP?
I learned that $\textsf{P/poly}$ is a class of problems computable by a polynomial-size circuit.
This class is considered a class of problems such that there exists a polynomial-time algorithm that is given a bitstring of $\textsf{poly}(n)$ length when the size of the input is $n$.
On the other hand, $\textsf{NP}$ is a class of problems where for any problem, there exists a poly-time algorithm $M$ such that for every input $x$, it is true iff there exists a bitstring $\alpha \in \{0,1\}^{\textsf{poly}(|x|)}$ such that $M(x,\alpha) = 1$.
Then, does it hold $\textsf{P/poly} \subseteq \textsf{NP}$ ?
I have searched for such results but found only the results about the inverse relation $\textsf{NP} \subseteq \textsf{P/poly}$.
Could you tell me the fact!!
I think that a bitstring of $\textsf{P/poly}$ is also used as the certification of $\textsf{NP}$.

You may want to check the Complexity Zoo entry for P/poly: https://complexityzoo.net/Complexity_Zoo:P#ppoly

This is not a research-level question, and should have been posted at https://cs.stackexchange.com . See e.g. https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/126933/is-p-poly-known-to-be-in-re .
